# "DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString" displays wrong time of day (offset by some hours)

Tags: c#, datetime

So i tried using the

```
 DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
```

method but it gives me the wrong time for example my current time is 9:09 PM but when i run the code it gives me 3:09 AM so pls help me.

Comment: See `DateTimeOffset.Now` as an alternative - in short it DateTimeOffset includes the TZ offset information, without having to worry about differences in local vs UTC.

Comment: Curious: when do you `DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset`, what is the result? Maybe the TZ information for the thread is wonkers. If that correctly returns "-6:00:00" then I suspect the thread's cultural info is [unexpectedly] forcing a UTC conversion in the display.

Answer (score 1):

Well , you could look into the TimeZoneInfo class. It can convert any time to utc time , then into the tomezone you want. ( see the methods  ConvertTimeToUtc and ConvertTimeFromUtc )
The advantage here is that it can be run on any 2 timezones

Comment: There should not be a need to do this as `DateTime.Now` returns a DateTime object of DateTimeKind.Local. Per the OPs post either 1) 'local' time is 'UTC' time - bad TZ context; or 2) the default culture information is formatting as UTC - bad/unexpected culture configuration.